# Pure JS - display:block not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, block

I know this has been asked a million times but I swear, I just checked like 20 posts and nothing works...

This is my code:

When a use clicks on the "Email" option, the input element with an ID of "email" should show underneath it.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled>Contact me by:</option>
    <option onclick="showInput()">Email</option>
</select>
<input class="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" />
```

JS

```js
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block";
}
```

CSS

```css
input#email {
    display: none;
}
```

Could someone explain to me how this is not working? 
I have a link to the JS file just before the body closing tag.

Comment: The missing " here: document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block; <---  . Is this a typo? Have you tried it in dif. browsers? The onclick event probably won't work in firefox, but in chrome

Comment: What isn't working? Your title says `display: none` but your post refers to "should show".

Comment: I don't think `<option>` elements fire "click" events, at least not in all browsers. That typo however would also prevent this from working; you've checked the developer console for errors, right?

Comment: @michael, It was a mistake when writing this post.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Pointy, really? That's crap. Thanks bud

Comment: @michael, I'm using Chrome but I tested it in Firefox & Safari. Non of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onChange` event and move the event handler to the `<select>` element. Also added a `value` attribute to the `<option>` element to make text field identification simpler. And, finally, in the function, pass the select element to the event handler and grab the selected option from the select list.

```
<select onChange="showInput(this)">
    <option selected disabled>Contact me by:</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
</select>
<input class="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" />

<script>

function showInput(sel) {
    var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
    document.getElementById(opt).style.display = "block"
}

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/2f0jw0yn/1/)

Now you can easily add more contact options:

```
<select onChange="showInput(this)">
    <option selected disabled>Contact me by:</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
    <option value="address">Mail</option>
</select>
<input class="email"   id="email"   placeholder="Email address"   type="text" />
<input class="phone"   id="phone"   placeholder="Phone number"    type="text" />
<input class="address" id="address" placeholder="Mailing address" type="text" />
```

Comment: Wow that's great! Thanks for your answer. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to hide an element when the other one is selected. So If I select "Email" and then click "Phone", the email would hide. Thanks bud!

Comment: You can set all elements to `none`, one at a time, before you set the selected element to `block`. Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/2f0jw0yn/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with `display: none;` at all. Your code doesn't work because it's impossible to attach `onclick` handler to `OPTION` element. Try this:

```
<select onchange="this.value === 'email' && showInput()">
```

It means "on selected option change check if email was selected and if it was, call `showInput` function".

You should add `value` attribute to `OPTIONS`, by the way.

**[See here](http://jsbin.com/covupe/2/edit?html,js,output)**.

Comment: Dzieki, Polak potrafi :)